# Left arrow doesn't work when I combine it with up arrow

Tags: keyboard

I think the title describes it all but here are some information. When I press left arrow + up arrow, left arrow doesn't work at all. I have to release up arrow so left arrow would work properly. I read some posts about this but those posts didn't actually help. I don't have a cheap keyboard. In fact, I didn't have this problem before re-installing the same version of windows. Any solutions? It's kinda annoying.

Comment: This is expected. If I open Excel and try to move up and left in a diagonal manner, by pressing left and up cursor, the selected cell only moves upwards.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a problem or limitation of your keyboard's ["key-rollover"](http://blog.controlspace.org/2010/08/n-key-rollover-what-it-is-and-how-to.html) feature.  Since it came by a reinstall of Windows, perhaps there is a driver needed to use all of the features for the keyboard.

Without the "key-rollover" feature, it is common to see keyboards only sending a key when a complete key press/release cycle is detected.  One relic of this is in the [X10 xterm mouse protocol](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-X10-compatbility-mode) which (mouse buttons are handled like keys) provided for mouse presses with three different buttons, but only one button release-code to complete the mouse-click events.